# how to pass command line arguments to getopt in perl

Tags: perl, getopt

I am new to Perl. I have to pass command line arguments to GetOptions method so I can access those variables. I have tried the following code:

```
  use Getopt::Long;
  $result = GetOptions($ARGV[0] => \$serv_name, $ARGV[1] => \$serv_id);
  print "Server name is $serv_name & server id is $serv_id";
```

But I am not getting desired output. So how do I do this?

Comment: How do you call the program?

Comment: on command line prompt by using "perl ex.pl aa 11"

Comment: whith `perl ex.pl --server_name=xxx --server_id=yyy` or `perl ex.pl xxx yyy`

Answer (score 3):

Try this (inspired from [documentation of Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html)):

```
use Getopt::Long;

GetOptions(
    "server_id=i"   => \my $serv_id,     # numeric
    "server_name=s" => \my $serv_name,   # string
) or die "Error in command line arguments\n";

print "Server name is $serv_name & server id is $serv_id\n";
```

If `server_id` argument maybe not numeric, change `"server_id=i"` to `"server_id=s"`

And call the program these ways:

```
%> perl ex.pl --server_name=the_name --server_id=1234
# or
%> perl ex.pl -server_name the_name -server_id 1234
```

Comment: But still i am getting error lke "Error in option spec: "server_name=xxx"

Comment: Did you call the script like I have shown in my example?

Comment: @user3839613 this answer works. (in recent perls) show your: `perl -MGetopt::Long -e 'print $Getopt::Long::VERSION'` and `perl -v`

Comment: @user3839613, who said to use "=xxx" in the option spec? MiguelPrz's code clearly uses "=s".